# php file loads slow if have many methods from classes

Tags: php

I have some concerns about my PHP file, which is processing too long.

I'm using XAMPP.

The problem is, that when i use too many methods of my classes, the PHP file loads too slow or it executes too slow.

Here's my example code:

```
class Sample {
    public function show() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

$classObject = new Sample();
$classObject->show();
```

When i run the PHP code above, it takes only i think `1.5s`, but if i add more method calls like this:

```
$classObject = new Sample();
$classObject->show();
$classObject->show();
```

the PHP code takes almost `3s` while executing.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

---

I already found out what is the problem is when i used oop style php while fetching data from my database it takes long secs before it gonna execute but when I used procedural php style it executes faster.

Comment: If simply calling the `show` function twice doubles the time it takes to execute, then seeing the contents of that function might help. But I'd guess that it's probably not class loading that's the problem, as code caching should make that almost instantaneous the second time around.

Comment: What is the code being run into `Sample::show()` ?

Comment: inside in a method show() its just a echo "test";

Comment: i think theres no problem in browser cause I already test in different kinds of browser but still have the same time of execution

Comment: and the text "test" its not a big size its just a normal text

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should take a look at some PHP debugging techniques, because i dont see any attempt of debugging in your code sample.

---

To your problem:

What you've described is an issue, that can be but must not be a fault of PHP. The thing is, you have to understand how request processing works ... in your case (XAMPP + PHP) it goes like this:

1. WebServer start:

   - XAMPP starts Apache (or Tomcat/or whatever WebServer you're using)
   - Apache starts PHP binary
   - PHP loads the configuration (`php.ini`)
2. The request:

   - You'll start a web browser (doesn't matter which one)
   - You'll enter a web address (with or without a specific path - `URI`)
   - *Then happens some DNS things - that's NOT important for you now*
   - *The browser sends a plain-text document on the server via the HTTP protocol, which communicates over TCP - also not so important for you at this time*
   - The WebServer receives a HTTP request and begins the processing
   - The WebServer runs your PHP script in the already running PHP binary and awaits the ouput
3. The response

   - Then the WebServer takes the output of your script and sends it back to the browser
   - The browser decides (by the headers) how (and if) the content will be displayed to you
   - Then the browser begins displaying the response content - in your case a HTML or a plain-text document
   - While drawing the document, the browser begins processing all JavaScript and CSS on the way (up to down)

---

**With this knowledge you need to find out WHERE on the way is the delay taking up time.**

The first thing you should do, is to take a look on how long your script is being processed, so:

```
<?php

$start_time = microtime(true);

$classObject = Sample();
$classObject->show();
$classObject->show();

echo 'Processing took: ' . number_format(microtime(true) - $start_time, 6, '.', '') . ' seconds';
```

Then, you should look into some Developer Tool your browser provides, for example [DevTools in Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (very good for debugging, though not the best) - hit `F12` to open it.

You'll see something like this:

[image: Chrome DevTools]

- **Time** is the duration between the time, the request was fully sent and the time, the response was fully received
- **Load** is the sum of durations of all the requests that were done at that moment
- **Finish** is the duration between the time the first request was fully sent and the time the last response was fully received
- **DOMContentLoaded** is the duration of rendering the entire document (browser/client side)

---

When you have all of this specific duartions, you can decide, where probably will be the problem :)

Comment: sir I already found out what is the problem is when i used oop style php while fetching data from my database it takes long secs before it gonna execute but when I used procedural php style it executes faster.

Comment: @VinceRyanSolier It would be great to put this information to the original question as an edit.

Comment: thank you sir, but i didn't still solve this problem because I really want to use oop style like fetching data from database but it seems hard for me because when i run my file it take almost a minute to execute.